# Suitescript 2 how to reference Bill transaction ID beforeSubmit on Payment page

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm writing a user event script beforeSubmit on the payment screen. How do reference the transaction ID of the bill that is being paid before the payment record is created? I need to know if I am paying an expense report or a normal vendor bill so I can prefix the check # field. This is what I have so far.

```
define(['N/record'],
function(record) {
     function beforeSubmit(context) {
        if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE)
            return;

        var customerRecord = context.newRecord;

>>>>>>  Not sure how to reference the Vendor Bill <<<<<

        var newprefix = 'EXP';
        newprefix += customerRecord.getValue('tranid');
        customerRecord.setValue('tranid', newprefix);
    }
    return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    };
});
```

thanks

*** The code I added to work out if the Vendor Bill is an Expense Report:

```
    var index = paymentRecord.findSublistLineWithValue({"sublistId": "apply", "fieldId": "apply", "value": "T"});

    var sublistFieldTranstype = paymentRecord.getSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'apply',
        fieldId: 'trantype',
        line: index
    });

    if (sublistFieldTranstype !== 'ExpRept')
        return;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to inspect the `apply` sublist to see which transaction(s) your Payment record is being applied to.

See the [Vendor Payments Record Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/vendorpayment.html) for all of the fields available in the `apply` sublist.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll post my code when I figure it out.

Comment: Code added above.